# How to make a gallery with items of different size

Tags: html, css

I want to make something like this:

[image]

I would like to do this with the most clean, semantic and responsive layout if is possible.

When I say clean, I refer to something like this.

```
<div class="gallery">
  <div>Item 1</div>
  <div>Item 2</div>
  <div>Item 3</div>
  <div>Item 4</div>
  <div>etc...</div>
</div>
```

And use CSS to align, rescale and reposition the items.

PD1: Is this possible with only html+css?

PD2: Is this possible with flexbox?

Comment: you should look at some online template. come to stackOverflow when you are stuck and have some code to stuck into.

Comment: check this url : http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/osFxj ... this might be helpful..

Comment: http://masonry.desandro.com/layout.html

Comment: @Sumesh S Great, Great, I didn't knew this method. Maybe it's not what I need right now, but I'll definitely check it out to learn because I know it will serve me in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well something *like* that would be to make the flow vertical and allow wrapping.

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box}
.gallery{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  height:300px;
  width:100%;
}
.gallery > *{
  flex:0 0 1;
  height:50%;
  background:teal;
  border:1px solid #000;
  color:#fff;
  padding:20px;
}
.gallery > :nth-child(5n){
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div>item 1</div>
  <div>item 2</div>
  <div>item 3</div>
  <div>item 4</div>
  <div>item 5</div>
  <div>item 6</div>
  <div>item 7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice! this is exactly what I was looking for, I was trying with flexbox too but I could not get this result.

Thank you!